# SQL Server 2005 Create a SQL Server failover cluster check button is not enabled

Tags: sql-server-2005, installation

I try to install SQL Server failover cluster under windows 2003 or windows 2008. In both installing time I found the checkbox enable error. I don't know any changes want to do to windows server before install this server cluster. I used windows 2008 enterprise version and SQL Server 2005 Enterprise edition. If it's can't explain like this way can you pass any step by step install web site or document, that is grate help to me.

Thank you
Suranga

Comment: It would help if you could post a screenshot of what you are talking about and seeing. I am not sure I fully understand with the way the question is phrased.

Comment: [Creating a Cluster in Windows Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2008/01/18/7151154.aspx) or a video [Configuring Failover Cluster in Windows Server 2008](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dONG4NWcgpE)